# Translate matlab code to python (scipy)

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, sparse-matrix

I' trying to translate this matlab code to python:

```
T = length(z);
lambda = 10;
I = speye(T)
D2 = spdiags(ones(T-2,1)*[1 -2 1],[0:2],T-2,T);
z_stat = (I-inv(I + lambda^2*D2'*D2))*z;
```

What I got at the moment:

```
T = len(signal)
lam = 10;
I  = np.identity(T)
D2 = scipy.sparse.spdiags(np.ones((T-2,1),dtype=np.int)*[1,-2,1],(range(0,3)),T-2,T);
```

At the moment I get this error

> "scipy.sparse.sp...ge(0,3)),T-2,T)"   ValueError: number of diagonals
>   (298) does not match the number of offsets (3)        args    tuple: ('number
>   of diagonals (298) does not match the number of offsets (3)',)

When looking at the documentation, the matlab function and the python function are very similar. Though there is probably a difference which I am missing.  My question is now: What am I doing wrong ?

**edit**: z is an array with length 300

Comment: Which version of python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you transpose the filter data to spdiags then you get an answer of the same dimensions in both packages:

```
# numpy/scipy
filt = [1,-2,1]* np.ones((1,T-2),dtype=np.int).T
D2 = scipy.sparse.spdiags(data.T, (range(0,3)),T-2,T)
np.shape(D2)
>>> (298, 300)

% matlab check
D2 = spdiags(ones(T-2,1)*[1 -2 1],[0:2],T-2,T)
size(D2)
ans =
  298   300
```