# Convert matlab code into python for matrix creation

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, scipy

I'm struggling to create the following matrix in python:

```
| 1 -2  1  0 ...  0  |
| 0  1 -2  1 ... ... |
|... ... ... ...  0  |
| 0  ... 0  1 -2  1  |
```

I've the matlab code below which seems to create this matrix ([article](https://bsamig.uef.fi/pdf/detrend.pdf)) but I cannot convert it in python code.

Matlab code:

```
D2 = spdiags(ones(T-2,1)*[1 -2 1],[0:2],T-2,T);
```

T is the number of columns.

The code in python looks like this:

```py
from scipy.sparse import spdiags
D2 = spdiags( (ones((T-2,1))*array([1,-2,1])),arange(0,3),T-2,T)
```

This latter produce the following error:

> ValueError: number of diagonals (327) does not match the number of
>   offsets (3)

But if I transpose the matrix like that:

```js
D2 = spdiags( (ones((T-2,1))*array([1,-2,1])).T,arange(0,3),T-2,T)
```

I get the following result:

```
matrix([[ 1., -2.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1., -2., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        ..., 
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., -2.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Does anybody can help me? Where am I wrong?

Comment: What T values are you working with? I'm not completely sure what's going on but it's worth noting that T=5 yields an apparently OK result when the first expression is evaluated (<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 9 stored elements (3 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030620/translate-matlab-code-to-python-scipy, it seems someone else was doing the same thing and had their question answered.

Comment: I found this question too. But actually it still doesn't work for me. T can be above 100. With smaller T value I can see that this works but it seems not completely. I expected that the end of the matrix ends with '1 -2  1' but actually as you can see it ends with '1 0 0'. I don't have matlab to see how exactly this function create the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
D2 = spdiags( (ones((T-2,1))*array([1,-2,1])).T,arange(0,3),T-2,T)
```

to this:

```
D2 = spdiags( (ones((T,1))*array([1,-2,1])).T,arange(0,3),T-2,T)
```

That is, you want the length of the rows in the first argument, which is the array containing the diagonals, to be equal the number of columns in the result.

Comment: That is the difference with matlab/octave! I've managed to execute the original code in octave and I get finally the same matrix and the expected results with your fix. Thanks Warren!